# Oracle query in a proc not returning results

Tags: c#, oracle, error-handling, plsql

I've this Pl/sql query in Oracle[10g] stored procedure which is called from C# program.:

```
SELECT a,b 
          FROM t1, t2 
         WHERE 
t1.Id=t2.Id
         AND NVL (TO_CHAR (t1.externalId), t2.product_name) = prm_product_name
```

prm_product_name is an input param to the proc and is declared as:

> prm_product_name VARCHAR2

App passes '1000' or '2000',etc as input param value to the proc and am able to get the query results succesfully in my C# app.
But when the app passes a particular number say 1500, the query does not return any records.I dont see any oracle exception in the application either.
When I modify the statement like below,recompile the proc, then the query proc returns results.

```
AND NVL (TO_CHAR (t1.externalId), t2.product_name) = '1500'
```

Also, am able to get the results from the proc when I invoke it using sql editor[without hardcoding 1500].Only when its called from the app, it does not return results.
Am not able to understand this behaviour and its root cause.
Could you please advise on how to get this working?

Thanks.

Comment: The behaviour you describe is hard to diagnose without seeing all the code in the stored proc.

Comment: that particular number is 1500? please post the procedure, and that number

Answer (score 0):

We would expect your procedure to hurl NO_DATA_FOUND in such circumstances.

Why doesn't it?  It's hard to say without seeing code for the whole stored procedure but money would be on a poorly-implemented exception section.  Something like this, which records the error but doesn't propagate the exception:

```
EXCEPTION
    WHEN no_data_found THEN
        write_error_log('no data for Product Name='||prm_product_name);
END;
```

Or even the dread

```
EXCEPTION
    WHEN others THEN
        null;
END;
```

which swallows the event as though the error never happened.

Comment: Thanks APC for ur inputs.But then am just wondering, how come the proc is giving results when run from sql editor for product name '1500'?Only when its called from the app,that it returns 0 results.This is what is baffling me.

Comment: Well that would baffle me too.  So simply, you must be doing something which you are not telling us.  For instance, is your C# app pointing at the same database as your SQL editor.